# Publishing a stream with agora.io

Tags: javascript, react-native, agora.io

I am using the Agora service for broadcasting. The package that I am using is [react-native-agora](https://github.com/syanbo/react-native-agora). I am having a hard time connecting exactly how to use the doc([publish stream](https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/publish_web_live?platform=Web)) with this package. They are sying that I should use the `client.createStream` method to be able to create a stream.

My problem is that If I look at the react-native-agora package they are importing

`import { RtcEngine, AgoraView } from 'react-native-agora';`

and if I log both of them I can't find any method saying createStream.

Answer (score 1):

The Agora React Native SDK follows the Native SDK API's and not the Web SDK API.

After calling `enableVideo()` on the engine, it will create the streams and publish the video.

From the SDK Documentation:

> Call the enableVideo method to enable the video mode. The voice
>   function is enabled by default in the Agora SDK, so you can call the
>   enableVideo method before or after joining a channel.
>
> - If you enable the video mode before joining a channel, you enter
>     directly into a video broadcast.
> - If you enable the video mode after
>     joining a channel, the voice broadcast switches to a video broadcast.

- iOS: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/publish_ios_live?platform=iOS
- Android: https://docs.agora.io/en/Interactive%20Broadcast/publish_android_live?platform=Android

Answer (score 0):

this is used for creatstream i think

const RCTAgoraView = requireNativeComponent("RCTAgoraView");

/**
 * AgoraView is the render layer for rendering video stream
 * 
 * This class is used to rendering native sdk stream
 * 
 * @props {@link AgoraViewProps}
 */